# Why is My Async Timer Blocking the UI Thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have a timer setup in my mainwindow code behind that fires every ten seconds. Because some of the code referenced in the timer_Elapsed event is somewhat CPU intensive I have placed it inside an `await Task.Run(() =>`, however the UI thread continues to hang momentarily whenever the elapsed event runs. Any ideas why this would be blocking the UI? Code:

```
async void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //Update default status bar text routinely
            try
            {
                if (ChecEnabled())
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        StatusText.Text = String.Format("Status: Enabled. Watching for changes…");
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                    {
                        StatusText.Text = String.Format("Status: Disabled");
                    });
                }
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException)
            {
                //Window closed and disposed timer on different thread
            }

            //System Checks
            UpdateSystemReadyStatus();
        });
    }
```

Comment: Is the `ChecEnabled()` the CPU intensive part? Could you post that code? Showing `UpdateSystemReadyStatus` would be good too.

Comment: Just to be clear - there is nothing in the code you've shown in the question so far that is causing your issue. You need to show the complete code so that we can be sure of giving you a good answer.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to start a Task in a Timer.Elapsed handler. The Timer is already running on a background thread.

Answer (score 4):

Update your `Invoke` to `InvokeAsync`. Also, do you really need to entire method wrapped in a `Task`?

```
async void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    //Update default status bar text routinely
    try
    {
        if (ChecEnabled())
        {
            await this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StatusText.Text = String.Format("Status: Enabled. Watching for changes…");
            });
        }
        else
        {
            await this.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                StatusText.Text = String.Format("Status: Disabled");
            });
        }
    }
    catch (ObjectDisposedException)
    {
        //Window closed and disposed timer on different thread
    }

    //System Checks
    await Task.Run(()=>UpdateSystemReadyStatus());
}
```